# What is a long, simplified, standard, alternative to an Array or LINQ?

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, debugging

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert Array into a primative method to express the same result, using no LINQ only int.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8865850/convert-array-into-a-primative-method-to-express-the-same-result-using-no-linq)

I've have got an issue with using arrays and LINQ. My program records 4 rooms and the number of bottles they collected. When the user types in quit, the program spits out the number of bottles each room as collected and the winning room with the most bottles.

The array I makes this code simple and an one pager. But I wasn't suppose to use arrays or anything complex, I was suppose to use a code knowledge from a freshman year. What ways or techniques could I use to simplify my code and achieve the same result?

I'm the most concerned with having to int room1, room2, room3, room4, but after that would I need a long if statement, or would a switch statement would be better. With the switch statement, would I need two? Because I would have to first switch the room I am in, and another switch to add on bottles to each room? Lastly, I'm not sure on how to find the room with Maximum number without an array. Math.Max is most ideal way, right?

I've thought this out pretty thoughtfully. The code below compiles without bugs. I've labelled everything I can.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {//Initialize array of rooms to 4
        int[] rooms = new int[4];
        //Start of while loop to ask what room your adding into. 
        while (true)
        {
            Console.Write("Enter the room you're in: ");
            // If user enters quit at anytime, the code will jump out of while 
            // statement and enter for loop below
            string quit = Console.ReadLine();
            if (quit == "quit")
                //Break statement allows quit to jump out of loop
                break; 

            // Variable room holds the number of bottles collect by each room. 
            int room = int.Parse(quit);
            Console.Write("Bottles collected in room {0}: ", room);
            // This line adds the count of bottles and records it so you can 
            // continuously count the bottles collected.
            rooms[room - 1] += int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        }

        // This for statement lists the 4 rooms and their bottle count when 
        // the user has entered quit. An alternative to below
        / *for (int i = 0; i < rooms.Length; ++i)
               Console.WriteLine("Bottles collected in room {0} = {1}", 
                                 i + 1, rooms[i]); */

        int maxValue = 0; // initiates the winner, contructor starts at 0
        int maxRoomNumber = 0; // initiates the room number that wins

        // This loop goes through the array of rooms (4)
        for (int i = 0; i < rooms.Length; ++i) 
        {
            // Makes sure that the maxValue is picked in the array
            if (rooms[i] > maxValue)
            {
                // Looking for room number for the 
                maxValue = rooms[i];
                maxRoomNumber = i + 1;
            } 

            // Writes the bottles collected by the different rooms
            Console.WriteLine("Bottles collected in room {0} = {1}", 
                              i + 1, rooms[i]);
        }

        // Outputs winner
        Console.WriteLine("And the Winner is room " + maxRoomNumber + "!!!"); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Without knowing what this "code knowledge from a freshman year" is, any solution we might offer runs the risk of violating the constraints that your instructor have given.  What is he looking for?

Comment: @George You've asked a lot of questions about the same piece of code. Perhaps you'd be better off discussing it in person with your tutor.

Comment: First assignment, I jumped the gun by using arrays now I have to dumb it down a little. This a practice assignment worth hardly marks. He's looking for a program that records bottles from 4 rooms. When the user types in quit, the bottle numbers are shown and the winner is choosen with the most bottles

Comment: @Matthew, I appreciate this community helping me, but its not about me trying to pester. I know I cannot get the answer I want every time but I try to constrain my question so it doesn't take along time to answer. I've asked some pretty broad questions before.

Comment: How often are you going to ask this question?

Comment: @Oded Its the first time today.

Comment: Not the point. Not first time on the site, so a repeat. If you need to update the question, go edit the original.

Comment: @Oded I don't know how to close my questions. Expand on a little knowledge not criticism .

Comment: I didn't say close. I said _edit_ the original. And you can delete your own questions after a couple of days, if they have no answers.

Comment: @Oded Will my edited question be bumped up?

Comment: Yes. Edit bump questions on the front page.

Comment: Ohkay, I will keep that in mind next time. I understand flooding questions is not what this community wants. But meh, cant go below 1 rep!

Comment: Thanks Henk, you forensic scientist. You caught me. Codes dont work on that page. Ill close it soon.

Comment: Comments like "But meh, cant go below 1 rep!" and "Thanks Henk, you forensic scientist" will not help your case. Try to keep your tone professional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8865983/880990) for `SetRoom` and `GetRoom` methods that do not use arrays.

Using `GetRoom` and the individual `int` member variables `Room1` to `Room4` you can find the room with the maximum number of bottles like this:

```
int maxValue = Room1;
int maxRoomNumber = 1;

for (int i = 2; i <= 4; i++) {
    int value = GetRoom(i);
    if (value > maxValue) {
        maxValue = value;
        maxRoomNumber = i;
    }
}
```

Note: The `Room1-4` variables must be declared as member variables. This means in the class, not in a method, for the `GetRoom` method to work.

Answer (score 0):

If your instructor thinks that arrays are complex, then I'm afraid he won't teach you anything practically useful. In my opinion a switch statement (which is what he probably expects) is more complex, error prone, smelly, and overall bad practice.

Rant aside, add 4 variables, one for every room and run through a swich statement. I'd prefer a switch since If ... Else if ... Else if ... Else would be even worse.

Comment: No he doesn't its complex. The first assignment is meant to be array less. We all know this program is much simpler with array.

Answer (score 0):

You only need one switch statement and you can keep track of which room collected the most bottles as the data is being entered.